# YAML - one to many object graph

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I use a snakeyaml (java) based parser to write a test case, and couldn't figure out how to properly build the graph. Any help, highly appreciated. thanks.

```
RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture test-data.yml: 
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by 
reflection getter of models.Priority.description
```

the above exception is for an unrelated field, and it works if I 
remove the association

```
roles: 
  - roleType: testRoleType 
    description: desc
```

If I change it to

```
- !models.Role 
      roleType:         testRoleType 
      description: desc
```

RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture test-data.yml: null; 
Can't construct a java object for !models.Role; exception=onRole 
Any help, highly appreciated. thanks.

```
public class Person {
String fullname;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Role> roles;
}

public class Role {
public RoleType roleType;
public String description;
}

public class RoleType {
public String roleName;
public String description;
}


YAML--

RoleType (testRoleType):
    roleName:      test
    description:   desc

Person(administrator):
    fullname:       Administrator
    roles:
      - roleType: testRoleType
        description: desc
```

Answer (score 1):

1) create your graph

2) Use SnakeYAML to serialize the object:

```
JavaBeanDumper dumper = new JavaBeanDumper();
String output = dumper.dump(graph);
```

3) see what comes out of it and change it manually.

P.S. !models.Role is a local tag and you should instruct SnakeYAML how to manage it.